# Is it OK to ask what the agenda will be for a phone interview

Tags: interviewing, job-search, pre-screening

I've been luckly enough to be offered a phone interview for a position I applied to. However, in the email it doesn't say what the agenda during the interview will be. I expect it to be an introduction, where I will be asked to go through my CV.

Is it OK for me to enthusiastically accept the interview, and ask what the agenda will be and who I will be talking to (HR or manager)?

Comment: The most important to ask is what is the duration. They should let you know how much time they will need from you so that you can arrange your schedule properly.